# Set cloned drive letter to C

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I want to switch my laptop HDD from the current 640GB device to a new 480 SSD HDD.

So I've shrinked and cloned my windows partition to the new disk; 100MB boot partition too

I've also set up the MBR on the new drive and marked the boot and active partition the same way it's on the original device.

but when I switched devices I get the error: `"winload.exe is missing or corrupt"`

I believe it is because the letter assigned to the device is G: instead of C:, but when I switch back and load windows there is no way to flip the drive letter assignment.

How can I fix the boot on the cloned drive so it boots just the same as the original?

Comment: What method have you used to clone it?

Comment: DriveImage XML disc to disc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any Windows 7 Install disc,

1/ Boot from it.
2/ When prompted with **'install now'** button, choose **'Repair your computer'** on the bottom left of the window.
3/ Choose the correct installation of windows and click Next
4/ When prompted to choose a recovery tool, click on **'Startup repair'**.

This should detect the problem and change the entry in the boot loader to target the right path.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to fix it without having to go to the store to buy a cd, but it is also the only way I know :(

Comment: @elcodedocle You don't have to buy it. See [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/q/78761/194694)

Comment: no, yeah. I know. I meant buying blank cd so I can burn a copy. I can also burn a windows repair disc (which is what I ended up doing), so no need for the download. (In fact there seems to be an easy way to make a usb drive install, but I didn't have a free usb drive at hand either. Just a linux boot cd and, appart from recovering the MBR using ms-sys, it didn't help much)